# `TypeError` when calling create(). You may need to make the field read-only, or override the create() method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Not sure what's going on here. I'm trying to perform create a new instance via Django-rest-framework. **What am I doing wrong?**

There are a few read-only fields being submitted back.
I've tried marking them as read-only via `read_only_fields` in the serializer, as well as specifying them as `editable=False` within the model's fields.

Note: I would prefer to avoid specifying my own create method if possible. This should work via standard functionality as documented [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields)

when POSTing the following:

```
{
  "displayName": "New test",
  "backgroundColour": "#4d3567",
  "foregroundColour": "#FFFFFF",
  "helpText": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "comment": "test."
}
```

i'm getting:

```
TypeError at /api/v1/classifications/
Got a `TypeError` when calling `ClassificationLabel.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `ClassificationLabel.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the ClassificationLabelListSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
```

**models.py**:

```
class ClassificationLabel(models.Model):
    """
    this model is used to create all instances of classifications 
    labels that will be displayed to a user
    """
    displayName = models.CharField('Classification label display name', max_length = 32)
    helpText = models.TextField('Explanatory text about this label', max_length = 140, blank=True)
    backgroundColour = models.CharField('Hex code for background colour including Alpha', max_length=8)
    foregroundColour = models.CharField('Hex code for foreground colour include Alpha', max_length=8)
    description = models.TextField('Description of this label', max_length = 256, blank=True)
    comment = models.TextField('Internal comments for this label', max_length = 1024, blank=True)
    lastChanged = models.DateTimeField('last changed timestamp', auto_now=True, editable=False)
    identifier = models.CharField('Classification label ID', max_length = 128, blank=True, editable=False)
    revision = models.PositiveIntegerField('Revision number for this label', default=1, editable=False)
    #placeholder for lastChangedBy

    def clean(self):
        #the following code generates a unique identifier and checks it for collisions against existing identifiers
        if not self.identifier:
            stringCheck = False
            while stringCheck is False:
                newString = str(uuid.uuid4())
                newString.replace('-', '')
                doesStringExist = ClassificationLabel.objects.filter(identifier=newString).count()
                if doesStringExist == 0:
                    stringCheck = True
            self.identifier = newString

    def __str__(self):
        return self.displayName + " - " + self.identifier

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        self.revision += 1
        super(ClassificationLabel, self).save(force_insert, force_update) # Call the "real" save() method.
```

**serializer:**

```
class ClassificationLabelListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ClassificationLabel
        fields = ('displayName', 'helpText', 'identifier', 'backgroundColour', 'foregroundColour', 'comment', 'description', 'lastChanged', 'revision')
        #read_only_fields = ('identifier', 'lastChanged', 'revision',)
```

**views.py**

```
class ClassificationLabelList(mixins.ListModelMixin,generics.GenericAPIView, mixins.CreateModelMixin):
queryset = ClassificationLabel.objects.all()
serializer_class = ClassificationLabelListSerializer

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**what seems to have fixed it**
an updated save() method seems to have fixed this. updated code below:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.revision += 1
        super(ClassificationLabel, self).save() # Call the "real" save() method.
```

Comment: Please add your view code

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev - now added

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe try something like this in your serializer,

```
class ClassificationLabelListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lastChanged = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    identifier = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    revision = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ClassificationLabel
        fields = ('displayName', 'helpText', 'identifier', 'backgroundColour', 'foregroundColour', 'comment', 'description', 'lastChanged', 'revision')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return ClassificationLabel.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Also, edit the save method in your models.py,

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.revision += 1
    return super(ClassificationLabel, self).save(*args, **kwargs) #
```

Comment: sorry, this didn't work. i'm still getting the same error: ```Got a `TypeError` when calling `ClassificationLabel.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `ClassificationLabel.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the ClassificationLabelListSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.```

Comment: try the edited answer, and see what's the error getting!!

Comment: interesting. the error i'm now getting is: ```TypeError at /api/v1/classifications/
save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'using'.```

Comment: Edit your save method and remove the `force insert` and `force_update` options

Comment: if you could update your answer with the updated save() method that I've just landed in the question i'll mark this as the accepted answer. thanks for your help :)