# Creating a record in django model through a POST request

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I'm pretty much new to Django and Rest Framework. So I trust you guys to help me fix my issue here. I'm on Python 2.7 and Django 1.11.

My models -

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField()
    completed_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self,force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        i = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
        in_tz = pytz.timezone("Asia/Calcutta")
        i = i.astimezone(in_tz)
        # If Item is being marked complete, set the completed_date
        if self.completed:
            self.completed_date = i
        super(Item, self).save(force_insert, force_update)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    ... ... ...
```

I'm trying to post a record to Item model which should get the user email from the request headers and should create the foreign key relation for that particular record.

My Serializer for the Item model-

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.RelatedField(source='User',read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

My Viewset for Item model -

```
class ItemViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    queryset = Item.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print 'Im in here', self.request.user
        user_id = User.objects.get(email=self.request.user)
        serializer.save(user= user_id)
```

I've checked few blogs and other questions on StackOverflow and reached till this point.

Now when I try to post a record am getting a TypeError as below

```
Got a `TypeError` when calling `Item.objects.create()`.
This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Item.objects.create()`.
You may need to make the field read-only, or override the ItemSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
Original exception was:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/../env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 943, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/../env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/../env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 394, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'
```

Kindly help me in fixing this for my use case. I'm short on time to get this done.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Must check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717250/typeerror-when-calling-create-you-may-need-to-make-the-field-read-only-or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need to override `perform_create`. All you need to do is change in serializer's [**`create`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) method:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('user')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['user'] = self.context["request"].user
        return super(ItemSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Here you should be able to get request object in serializer because ViewSet sends the `request` object through [**`extra context`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context). I am just adding `user` object from serializer to `validated_data`. I also got rid of `user` field, instead added it to the [**`read_only_fields`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields).

Comment: Thank you @ruddra . I tried this method. I've removed the perform_create method from the ViewSet. I'm not getting the request object to this serializer. Thus the following error ```'ItemSerializer' object has no attribute 'request'```

Comment: Oops. My bad. I fixed the answer. please try it again.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this before you edit and the same TypeError exists. ```TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'```

Comment: Please share the full stacktrace

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've overlooked the save method in the model. I've tweaked that a bit and your solution worked.