# I get a Type Error when posting data using via REST. It says I may have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

full error:

```
Got a `TypeError` when calling `Certificate.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Certificate.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the CertificateSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
```

I have a certificate model which has the clean() and get_remote_image() methods since there are two options of posting image to my database, either with urls or file upload - so when one is already selected the other one is no longer needed. if url is the selected option, it saves to the image field.

I get the error when posting data.

models.py

```py
class Certificate(models.Model):
    certificate_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    template_img = models.ImageField(blank=True, default='', upload_to='certificate_templates')
    template_url = models.URLField(blank=True, default='')
    names_file = models.FileField(blank=True, default='', upload_to='names_files')
    names_csv = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    Y_RATIO = 1.6268

    def get_remote_image(self):
        if self.template_url and not self.template_img:
            img_result = requests.get(self.template_url)
            img_name = os.path.basename(self.template_url)
            with open(os.path.join(TEMP_DIR, img_name), 'wb') as img_file:
                img_file.write(img_result.content)
            self.template_img.save(
                img_name,
                open(os.path.join(TEMP_DIR, img_name), 'rb')
                )
            self.save()


    def clean(self):
        if not self.template_img and not self.template_url:
            raise ValidationError({'template_img': 'Either one of template_img or template_url should have a value.'})
        if not self.names_csv and not self.names_file:
            raise ValidationError({'names_csv': 'Either one of names_csv or names_file should have a value.'})


    def save(self):
        if self.template_url and not self.template_img:
            self.get_remote_image()
            super(Certificate, self).save()
        else:
            super(Certificate, self).save()
```

serializers.py

```py
class CertificateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Certificate
        fields = ('certificate_name', 'template_img',
            'template_url', 'names_file', 'names_csv')
```

i saw at similar problem [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717250/typeerror-when-calling-create-you-may-need-to-make-the-field-read-only-or) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44997315/django-rest-framework-got-a-typeerror-when-calling-note-objects-create) that the save method shouldnt have arguments but mine already doesnt have arguments.